# Create simple PDF from Text files in .NET

Tags: .net, xslt, pdf, text, xsl-fo

I am looking for a way to create PDF files from simple Text files in .NET.

There is no fancy formatting, pictures or graphs. Only one font(courier new) and font-size throughout the PDF. Basically I want to save the contents of the Text file to a PDF file as is. I may need to set the orientation and margins of pages. It is a simple process.

I don't want to use any third party library for conversion. I have used iTextSharp and PDFTechLib in past. I want to get rid of these products because of cost involved and licencing issues.

I have also looked in using XSL-FO and Apache FOP to achieve this. It looks rather complex to get this simple task done.

Is there any inbuilt .NET Class to achieve the task? OR something similar.

Comment: Have you looked at PDFSharp?  http://pdfsharp.com  It's open source but has a very friendly license.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement and I was not able to find **good** libraries in .net for free. I finally settled with [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/). This is not a .net library but I used [System.Diagnostics.Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class to start this exe through .net code.

Answer (score 0):

Using Apache FOP may appear complex, but I would recommend to go that way anyway, partly because you will be able to apply it in all situations where you wish to create pdf from xml or text sources. And it also allows for fancy formatting like adding pictures :-).
Roughly, using FOP means doing a two-step process, first creating an fo xml basis by applying an xslt (also called xsl-fo) on the input file, and then creating the pdf from the saved fo xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Is a free PDF-printer driver anything that would match your criteria?

Googled it and this was the first result, but there are many other out there. (This particular product is FREE for personal and commercial use up to 10 users):  http://www.bullzip.com/products/pdf/info.php

I use PDF-printing a lot, its easy and I get the same result when printing to printer and to PDF.

Edit: This driver seems to be free for both commersial and personal use: http://www.dopdf.com/

Answer (score 0):

I came across an interesting alternative which I have to study and test first, but this may be exactly what you are looking for: [css2xslfo](http://www.re.be/css2xslfo/index.xhtml).
Download and manual available from links on that site.

Answer (score -1):

How about the project iTextSharp. You can find it on http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/